# Java data structure for counting card in players hand

Tags: java, data-structures

the player always have 4 card, and they are stored in an array, the player needs to select the most unwanted card and return the index of the unwanted card(from 0 to 3),  and the rule follows

1. If a single rank appears the most in the player’s hand, then a card of differing rank is selected randomly.
2. Otherwise, a card is selected randomly from the player’s entire hand.

I have spend two hours on it, the problem is that I need to know occurrence of each card rank and their position in the array, so I used

```
Map<Rank, ArrayList<Integer>>
```

and the decision making part is extremely messy, is there a better way to do this?

example:

if my hand is A,10,10,A then I randomly select one.
if my hand is 3,3,3,A  then I select A
if my hand is 2,2,4,5 then I randomly select 4,or 5.
if my hand is A,2,3,4 then I randomly select one.

Comment: I don't see any of your algorithm or logic in your post just yet.

Comment: This is difficult to read.

Comment: Thats what I was asking. I don't know the good algorithm, it would be pointless to put my messy code on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define model classes, instead of trying to keep track of everything in maps of array lists.

```
public class Card {
    private String rank;
    private String value:
}
```

.

```
public class Hand {
    private List<Card> cards;
}
```

.

```
public class Player {
    private Hand hand;
}
```

.

```
public class CardGame {
    private List<Player> players;
}
```

You can fill out these model classes with the rest of the game information.